# What is the best way to transfer data between two tabs in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I need to transfer data from one website form to another using chrome extension.

I have the basic files:

- manifest.json
- popup.html
- content.js
- background.js

I can get the data using `content.js`:

```
let title = document.getElementById("title").value;

chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
    {
        title: title,
    }
)
```

How can I send it to the other tab?

**Edit**

In my `background.js`:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener (
    function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
        alert(request.title)
});
```

Comment: Like Sergey said, you should use [messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) but, also note that instead of [`onMessageExternal`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/runtime#event-onMessageExternal) you must use [`onMessage`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/runtime#event-onMessage) instead inside your `background.js` in order for it to work since you are only sending it from your `content.js` and not from an **External** source.

Comment: You can exchange via chrome.storage.local and chrome.storage.onChanged listener without the background page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you need to transfer something between two entities, you need a common medium. Be it sound (Air) or words(Language).

In this case, you need to transfer data from one website to another. Possible common mediums are :-

1. Server
2. Chrome Extension (via background)

In case of server, you need to ensure that 
1. Message from user1 does not reach to user2 
2. Message from site1 should be delivered to correct recipient site

In case of chrome extension you just need to ensure #2 So definitely going with chrome extension background process is a better approach.

### Workflow

```
Site_1_Content_Script ---> Background --- > Site_2_Content_Script
```

### Solution with pseudocode

1. From Site 1, Send Message to background with message and recipient details

```
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
      message: message.,
      source: source_domain,
      destination: destination_domain
    }, function(resp) { });
```

2. Receive message in background and send it to to other tab

```
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResp) {
      chrome.tabs.query({ url: request.destination_domain }, function(tabs) {
      // Send message to each tab matching that domain/url
    }
```

3. Receive message un content script

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to send it from one content script (tab) to other.
You need to do it through your background page script.

It will be like this:

> send a message from CS to BG page -> process message on BG page and
>   send it to another tab

You can find documentation on [messaging here](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/messaging).